# Store Views - 404 Error - Magento 1.8 & 1.9

Tags: store-view, 404-page

I have 2 store views in magento.

I have both Store Views under one website and one store:
[image]

Then in System Config I have each store view set the same:

[image]

Lastly Categories are set to redirect to static blocks with translations in them.

[image]

However when I visit these links I am redirected to a Error (404) page and back to the default site/language. Any ideas?

Comment: Are product category pages working OK? Have you tried to enable `Add Store Code to URL`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't respond.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System =>Configuration => Web => Add Store Code to Urls => yes then Clear Catche

Hope this will help you ?

Comment: Hi,I was able to resolve this by adding a store code. Sorry I posted this question in Dec and didn't see a response until 3 days ago...